# error using PKCS#12 certificate to sign some data with Java

Tags: java, pkcs#12

I'm trying to use a PKCS#12 certificate to sign some data.
I signed the data successfully in the development machine, but after I deployed the application into production machine I run into some problem.

In the development machine I have Oracle jdk 1.6.0 and centos 6.2 and in the production machine there is IBM jdk 1.6.0 with IBM AIX.

The problem is that I can't get the private key with it's alias out of the KeyStore instance which is loaded with the certification file , 
it seems that there is no entry in the KeyStore, while I have printetd the entries which exist in the certification file with
keytool command(so there is no problem with the file), also this code runs in the development machine without any problem.

any help is appreciated

Here is the code:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
String certFileAbsPath =  this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath() + File.separator + "file.p12";
File file = new File(certFileAbsPath);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
ks.load(fis, null);
Enumeration aliasEnum = ks.aliases();
String aliasName = null;
while(aliasEnum.hasMoreElements()){
    aliasName = (String)aliasEnum.nextElement();
    logger.debug("alias: " + aliasName);//nothing is logged!
}
```

Comment: Define 'deployed`. How did the keystore get into the production environment?

Comment: I have a ".p12" file which is bundled with the WAR file of the application and  WAR file is deployed into the tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience Java doesn't like PKCS#12 keystores that don't have a password. Set a password on your PKCS#12 file (it doesn't have to be a strong one, just "password" is fine) and provide that as the second argument to `ks.load`.

Comment: but the odd thing is that the code runs in my development machine like a charm

Comment: I converted the certification file from pkcs12(.p12) to java key store(jks) with keytool command and as you said I set a password for it, It's resolved now :)

Answer (score 1):

> I have a ".p12" file which is bundled with the WAR file of the application and WAR file is deployed into the tomcat.

In other words it's a resource. `new File()` and `new FileInputStream` can't deal with resources. You should be using `Class.getResourceAsStream()`.

It works in development because the file exists there. It doesn't exist in production. Only the resource exists, inside the WAR file.

Comment: Nothing has changed that affects my answer. It's still a resource; you still can't use `File` or `FileInputStream` on it; and you should still be using `Class.getResourceAsStream()`.

Comment: Actually it isn't intended to be a resource, so the question is that what I have to do to use it as a file instead of a resource? Do I have to put certification out of tomcat and provide the File instance with the absolute path of it?

Comment: If it isn't intended to be a resource, don't put it in the WAR file; use your original code; and make sure when you deploy that the file is in the place expected by the code.

Comment: I've tried a new aproach based on your suggestion,
I put the certificate file in a directory out of tomcat(for example /user/home/certification), and 
I used its absolute path to intialize the File instance 
`File file = new File("/user/home/certification/file.p12")` ,
but the result is the same, I get the same Exeption.