# Signing and Verifying in java with pkcs#12 certificate

Tags: java, digital-signature, signing, verify, pkcs#12

Recently I've involved in a project which I have to write some code to sign some text data and send it to an other application which is implemented in C#.

I have posted about two of my problems which I have. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29768399/error-using-pkcs12-certificate-to-sign-some-data-with-java) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888312/signing-text-data-with-pkcs12-certification-in-java).

Actually the project is not going very well, and I'm stuck into the signing process for several days.
The problem is that the signature which I have made can not be verified by the other application, also I can not verify their signature too.

I have received a pkcs12 certificate(.p12) file which contains 3 entries as below:

1. RootCA(certificate + public key)
2. SubCA(certificate + public key)
3. test_dig_sig(certificate + public key + private key)

I have followed [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-sec1/j-sec1.html) tutorial 
to implement the signing and verifying process.

Actually what I'm looking for is an overview of the signing and verifying implementation.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

To handle S/MIME in Java, use [Bouncycastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/)

Their documentation is not the best you could hope for but there are quite a lot of examples provided with the code

Check the examples in the package **org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.examples**